# Comprehensive & Challenging Textbooks for Parametric Equations, Polar Coordinates, etc.? [Sophomore Physics Student]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

I'm a sophomore Physics student and I want to refresh my knowledge on these pre-calculus topics. I initially learned them from Cohen's Precalculus/Trigonometry book:

[https://www.amazon.com/David-Cohen-Precalculus-Trigonometry-Tutorial/dp/B004K39WKW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004K39WKW)

and while the trig sections were comprehensive enough, the sections on the topics mentioned above didn't feel complete. Any suggestions for textbooks that I should use? The more comprehensive/challenging the better, as I don't want to have to relearn these topics again in the future (barring super-specific extra topics).

Also, is this even a valid concern or should I just proceed with Calculus/Linear Algebra/Math Methods textbooks (i.e. Spivak, Boas, Friedberg, etc.) and learn additional pre-calc topics as I go?

P.S. While I appreciate theory, I'm trying to avoid textbooks that are geared towards Pure Math majors since I'm mostly reviewing these topics for peace of mind as I tackle more advanced Physics subjects.

Comment: Why not trying the  OpenStax's Calculus textbooks , written under the direction of Gilbert Strang , in particular Calculus III . These references are perfect for self study. You can download a free PDF version , and also order a copy. The OpenStax project is sponsored by Rice University.

Comment: @VinceVickler So should I skip ahead to calculus instead of lingering in these topics?